# visual studio 2010 debugger hanging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

The debugger is hanging intermittently but frequently for no obvious reason. It times out eventually and recovers.

I am using vs 2010 Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel, running a 4.0 client app on a Vista 64 o/s.

Has anyone else been having this issue too, and have a fix?

As a related aside, anyone know if there are any service releases yet??

Cheers,
Berryl

Comment: Had the same issues in the beginning, but downloaded previous versions of .NET (2.0, 3.0, 3.5) - and all works fine (by now) on Windows7 Pro.

Comment: @Benny - are you saying your target was something less than 4.0 or that downloading prior versions fix a 4.0 target?

Comment: When i downloaded the lower .NET-versions I also got the option to download something else connected to .NET 4 framework. Unfortunately I cannot remember what that something was :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in 2005 and 2008 this happens all the time as well.  Usually it has to do with (a) loading symbols from a public symbols server (yeah network I/O on the UI thread!), or (b) intellisense, or (c) you're debugging the network stack (or some other OS component) and Visual Studio is trying to use it (and things deadlock).  If (b), wait for it to finish doing its thing before you start debugging.  Sucks up front, but saves you time and frustration in the long run.

Comment: I was thinking symbols too, but didn't think it was going over the net to get them. Is there a way to stop that or shorten the timeout period? My other thought was something weird with open windows including those by 3rd parties (ie, resharper), because I notice vs 2010 takes an awful long time to close all of 5 or so open windows and crashes more when I change some window setting. Cheers

Comment: Well, it only does it if you have a symbol server setup.  Check Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols.  It should have a list of symbol locations.  Things like Microsoft Symbol Servers, or http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols, or http://symbols.mozilla.org/firefox...  You can check "Only Specified Modules" to disable it doing it automatically, then you can rclick->Load Symbols the modules in the modules window if you want to specifically load symbols for it.  Depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

There are no service packs for Visual Studio 2010 yet. I've also had problems in the debugger, and sadly the best advice I can give that has worked for me is to exit Visual Studio and re-open it.

Comment: Try waiting five seconds or so longer and see if the debug session times out. It sucks just slightly less than force quitting and restarting.